# Error WCSAPI in Find WLANS in motorola MC2180

Tags: windows-ce

After first reboot the wireless profile is configured and operational, but after next reboot can't connect, and when you try to find wlan, it shows the following error:

> WCSAPI Error SetScan Failed (0xC001000D)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation the solution is to create a new profile with a different name, because for any unknow reason the previous profile was corrupted. 
If this not solve the issue, maybe you will enforced to change ssid from wlan network you want to connect, and then create a new profile.